# Transaction is automatically going to Rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, ado.net, batch-processing

We are running an Long Running SP through ADO.NET Asynchronous BEGINEXecuteNonQuery, SP ran for 12 Hours, this sp performs batch inserts from one table to another table about 6,00,00,000 records.

While performing Batch Inserts when I check status, Query goes to suspended mode for some time ( I think it is waiting for IO resources) and comes back to running mode, goes back to suspended for some time, after waiting another 15 min, if I check status, I see SPID has "RollBack' not in RUNNING state. I haven't canceled transaction and not sure why the status is showing has RollBack, Not sure reasons for rollback state an SPID.

Anyone face the same issue previously? How to handle this scenario?

Comment: DBCC INPUTBUFFER(spid) will tell you last message sent from client to SQL Server. Can you try running the SP in SSMS with output messages?

Answer (score 2):

Your SP is probably returning an error that might tell you what's going wrong.

Use `BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback, Object)` in order to check the query outcomes:

[SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also analyse the server log:

[View Error Logs](http://sqlmag.com/stored-procedures/view-error-logs).